# python for android is not installing on my raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, installation, kivy

I download the p4a from the clone link and I try to install it with

pip install python-for-android

It says is successfully install but when i run

python-for-android recipes

to see if it works, it says

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python-for-android recipes
bash: python-for-android: command not found

/home/pi/python-for-android

Comment: Note the `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: /home/pi/python-for-android

Comment: What is your reply meaning? Just check if there is an executable `python-for-android` (known from your question) exists in any folder mentioned in `$PATH`. If no folder in `$PATH` contains that executable, and you know where the executable locates in, just modify this environment variable to go.

Comment: Run `whereis python-for-android` and then try executing it with the absolute path, that way you know that what Geno Chen is saying makes sense.

Comment: It doesn't exist

Comment: This p4a call should work and you can try to debug it, but I'm afraid python-for-android won't work on rpi anyway because the Android build tools are not available for arm cpus.

Comment: On my old sd card on rpi, buildozer was going past the p4a step without finding errors